# How to read EPS file in c# and is there any possibility to write something on the top of the file and then export in pdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, adobe, eps

I have got a requirement where the client would provide me a .eps(Encapsulated PostScript) file and i have to write some content on the top of eps file and then convert it to PDF. I am not getting how to achieve this functionality, if someone can help me by suggesting how can we read EPS file using C# and can do some modification(please suggest if there is some other format which allows editing and eps file can easily be convertible in that format).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use external tools Use **Gimp** with **Ghostscript** plugin.
I dont know Gimp can export to pdf or not, if not you can use **Neevia Document Converter** to export modified EPS to PDF after edited with Gimp

http://www.gimp.org/

GhostScript plugin http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-external-programs.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!

Is Neevia Document Converter a freeware?

and is there any way to convert SVG file to PDF but i need only freeware(dll) and which can be embedded into my project means compatible for c# project